# C#: Value property of DateTimePicker not compatible with Date/Time of MS Access database 2013

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, forms, ms-access-2013

I am trying to implement a timestamp that would go inside an ms access 2013 table, inside a C# app using the .NET framework and visual studio 2013, to keep a record of who has logged on inside my app, but I get an error that my INSERT INTO statement has a syntax problem, but when I remove the timestamp parameters all together, and stop using the datetimepicker, the app will manage to insert the username and password inside the database with success, so i reckon there is a compatibility problem between the Date/Time field of ms access 2013 and the value of the datetimepicker tool inside visual studio framework. So now, i ask you, what is the best method to get the current correct date and time and insert it into the said database? I have tried setting the field as a short text and setting the now property of datetime .ToString, that does not work either.

```
private void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LibrarieConectare"].ConnectionString))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = connect.CreateCommand();
            OleDbCommand _logins = connect.CreateCommand();
            dateTimePickerBirthAngajat.Value = DateTime.Now;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", textBoxAccount.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBoxParola.Text);
            _logins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utilizator", textBoxAccount.Text);
            _logins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parola", textBoxParola.Text);
            _logins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", dateTimePickerBirthAngajat.Value);
            command.CommandText = "SELECT IDAngajat FROM Angajati WHERE NumeUtilizator=@user AND Parola=@pass";
            _logins.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Logins (Utilizator, Parola, TimeStamp) VALUES (@utilizator, @parola, @datetime)";

            connect.Open();

            try
            {
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                        user = textBoxAccount.Text;
                        parola = textBoxParola.Text;
                        if (rememberMe.Checked == true)
                       {
                           _logins.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       }  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                        MessageBox.Show("Login failed!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Eroare baza de date: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly parsing your Date as a `DateTime` object instead of passing in a string via the [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method :

```
// Parse your date as an actual Date
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateTimePickerBirthAngajat.Value);
// Pass that parameter along to be executed
_logins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", date);
```

Depending on how your Date is formatted, you may actually need to use the [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which will allow you to supply a formatting string (e.g. "MM/dd/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd", etc.) to indicate how your string should be parsed in.

Comment: After some searching , I found out that my SQL query was using a keyword that access was using to communicate with the database trough queries, which was the word "TimeStamp", so I needed to write it as this:"[TimeStamp]", but your answer resolved my problem parsing the date in a correct format for my needs. Thank you!

Comment: The [DateTimePicker#Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is already a `DateTime` so using `DateTime.Parse` on it makes no sense.